# Column in the j-expression of a data.table (with/without a by statement)

Tags: r, data.table, plyr

Here are two artificial but I hope pedagogical examples of my problem.

**1)** When running this code:

```
> dat0 <- data.frame(A=c("a","a","b"), B="")
> data.table(dat0)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) length(A)) , by = "A"]
   A B
1: a 1
2: b 1
```

I expected the output

```
   A B
1: a 2
2: b 1
```

(similarly to `plyr::ddply(dat0, .(A), nrow)`).

## Update to question 1)

Let me give a less artificial example. Consider the following dataframe:

```
dat0 <- data.frame(A=c("a","a","b"), x=c(1,2,3), y=c(9,8,7))
> dat0
  A x y
1 a 1 9
2 a 2 8
3 b 3 7
```

Using `plyr` package, I get the means of `x` and `y` by each value of `A` as follows:

```
> ddply(dat0, .(A), summarise, x=mean(x), y=mean(y))
  A   x   y
1 a 1.5 8.5
2 b 3.0 7.0
```

Very nice. Now imagine another variable `H` and the following calculations:

```
dat0 <- data.frame(A=c("a","a","b"), H=c(0,1,-1), x=c(1,2,3), y=c(9,8,7))
> ddply(dat0, .(A), summarise, x=mean(x)^mean(H), y=mean(y)^mean(H))
  A         x         y
1 a 1.2247449 2.9154759
2 b 0.3333333 0.1428571
```

Very nice too. **But now, imagine there's a huge number of variables `x` for which you want to calculate `mean(x)^mean(H)`**. Then I don't want to type:

```
ddply(dat0, .(A), summarise, a=mean(a)^mean(H), b=mean(b)^mean(H), c=mean(c)^mean(H), d=mean(d)^mean(H), ...........)
```

So my idea was to try:

```
flipcols <- my_selected_columns # c("a", "b", "c", "d", ....)
data.table(dat0)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) mean(x)^mean(H)), by = "A", .SDcols = flipcols]
```

But that doesn't work because the presence of `H` in `function(x) mean(x)^mean(H)` is not handled as I expected! I have not been able to make it work with `plyr::colwise` too.

**2)** When running this code:

```
> dat0 <- data.frame(A=c("a","a","b"), B=1:3, c=0)
> data.table(dat0)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) B), .SDcols="c"]
Error in ..FUN(c) : object 'B' not found
```

I expected it works and generates :

```
   c
1: 1 
2: 2 
3: 3
```

So is there a way to use the columns of the original data.table in a transformation ?

Comment: What do you want to do in the second example? assign the values of B to c??

Comment: @RandyLai Of course, no. The example is artificial. The problem is that `function(x) B` involves `B` which is a column of the dataframe, you can imagine the function you want instead of this stupid function.

Comment: but `lapply` applies to the columns of the subset, why do you have a `B` inside the function? see my answer for comparison.

Comment: @RandyLai please see the update of the 1st question

Comment: @Arun I have updated question 1) to provide a more specific example.

Comment: it is because `lapply` applies to columns of the subset. it returns a list of length = `ncol(.SD)`

Comment: Your update of problem (1) boils down to your (2).

Comment: see my updated answer. the reason of all problems is the incorrect use of `lapply`

Comment: @Arun No: in 1), the column in the body of the functino appears in the `by` statement, not in `2`, and that causes a different behavior.

Comment: @Arun as mentionned by eddi, problem 2 is due to `.SDcols`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent modified (1) is the same problem, again due to `.SDcols`

Comment: @Arun Yes you're right, removing `.SDcols` solves the main problem ! But why it doesn't work for the first example before my update ?

Comment: because you shouldn't use `length`, but `nrow`, see my questions.

Comment: @RandyLai Your answer works for the "length-calculation" problem, but `data.table(dat0)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) nrow(A)) , by = "A"]` does not work, thus your answer does not answer to the conceptual problem.

Comment: `data.table(dat0)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) length(A)) , by = "A"]` will not work, because `A` is assigned to be the group key in each subset, to get something similar to work, you can replace `A` by `H`: `data.table(dat0)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) length(H)) , by = "A"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** Use `.N`. The length of the grouping variable `A` there is 1 because there is just one value of `A` for each group (this is by definition of what grouping means):

```
dt <- data.table(A=c("a","a","b"), B="")
dt[, .N, by = A]
#   A N
#1: a 2
#2: b 1
```

**(updated 1)** This is the same issue as 2). A workaround is to not use `.SDcols`:

```
dt = data.table(A=c("a","a","b"), H=c(0,1,-1), x=c(1,2,3), y=c(9,8,7))
dt[, lapply(.SD[, !"H"], function(x) mean(x) ^ mean(H)), by = A]
#   A         x         y
#1: a 1.2247449 2.9154759
#2: b 0.3333333 0.1428571
```

**2)** This is a bug that's been reported before here: https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5222&group_id=240&atid=975

Comment: (1) is not a desired feature to have either IMHO. [Bug #5191](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5191&group_id=240&atid=975) is a product of this feature. I don't think `by` variables should mask the original columns in `x`. This is under discussion still.

Comment: Thank you eddi. But my question is a conceptual one: this is an artificial example, my question about how  to use a column in a function in general, not for this specific example.

Comment: @Arun hmm, I thought that bug was about masking of columns for complicated by expressions - I'm not sure I see why you'd want the full column in a simple by-expression like this one

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent perhaps you can give a different example then - I don't really know what you want atm - generally speaking - just use the columns (and most of the time you don't need `.SD`) - I assume you're having more specific issues.

Comment: @eddi, the simplest reason is that there's already a variable `.BY` that allows access to the grouping variable values. So why mess `x's` column up? From your `dt`, try: `dt[, A, by=list(A)]` and `dt[, A, by=list(C=A)]` - this is just confusing.

Comment: @Arun that's a solid example, sold :) *caveat: this will mess up a lot of my code :( (adding stuff as I think about it) the vast majority of the time (always?) I use the grouping variable in the `j`-expression, I need it to be a single element and not a vector, so as disturbing as that example might seem, I'm not a fan of doing this just for "consistency" (in quotes, because I'm not convinced there is an obvious inconsistency)

Comment: @eddi  I have updated question 1) to provide a more specific example.

Comment: @eddi You're right about question 2), the problem is caused by the `.SDcols` argument

Comment: @eddi Ok removing `.SDcols` solves the main problem in the update of my first question. So for the original question before the update, the problem is that `A` is at the same time in the j-expression and in the `by` statement ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent for the original question the issue is that by variables are *single* values. For each group there is just one value (by the definition of what grouping means), and as such, the length of that is 1.

Comment: @eddi Ok I see. It would be nice if you include this sentence in your answer: *by variables are single values*, this is the root cause of the problem. Thank you !

Comment: Thank you again @eddi I have applied this to my real example now. Do you know if something similar to question 1' (update of question 1) is doable with `(d)plyr` ? (I mean a "one-line" solution, and I have not been able to do it with the `colwise` function)

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent probably, but it's going to be uglier and slower :) you may need to ask a separate question to get an answer from `(d)plyr` gurus

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand you correctly.

1)

```
library(data.table)
dat0 <- data.frame(A=c("a","a","b"), B="")
data.table(dat0)[, list(l= nrow(.SD)) , by = "A"]
```

result:

```
   A l
1: a 2
2: b 1
```

2)

```
dat0 <- data.frame(A=c("a","a","b"), B=1:3, c=0)
data.table(dat0)[, list(c=unlist(.SD)), .SDcols= "B"]
```

result:

```
   c
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3
```

1')

**Edit:** I changed `-1` to `mycols`

```
dat0 <- data.frame(A=c("a","a","b"), H=c(0,1,-1), x=c(1,2,3), y=c(9,8,7))

data.table(dat0)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) mean(x)^mean(H)), by = "A", .SDcols = c("x", "y")]
```

result:

```
   A         u         v
1: a 1.2247449 2.9154759
2: b 0.3333333 0.1428571
```

Note that if the data is huge, `mean(H)` will be calculated many times wastefully. We could do `{muH = mean(H); lapply(.SD, function(x) mean(x)^muH)}` in this case to save computation; the above is a bit more readable though.