# data.table converts factors in `by` to underlying integer?

Tags: r, data.table

Consider:

```
dt <- data.table(a=factor(rep(c("a", "b"), 5)), b=1:10)
dt[, list(mean(b), a), by=a]
```

Produces:

```
   a V1 a
1: a  5 1
2: b  6 2
```

Also:

```
Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':  2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a : Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": 1 2
 $ V1: num  5 6
 $ a : int  1 2
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Note the last column.  The actual `by` column itself is fine, the problem arises when you try to re-use the `by` column explicitly in `j`.  I also believe the `.BY` variable has the same issue.  This is in 1.9.2 with R 3.0.2 and Rstudio on Win 7 (though observed on Mac OS 10.8 as well).  This used to work on earlier versions (not sure which, from memory so could be wrong).

Posting here first in case I'm doing something stupid.

Also, it seems that the ungrouped `by` variable is no longer available.  For example:

```
dt[, list(mean(b), a[[2]]), by=a]
```

produces an out of bounds error, though perhaps that was always the case.  I would have expected `a` in `j` to be fully evaluated in `dt`, so `a[[2]]` should work (in my head anyway, perhaps it never did and was never intended to).

Session info:

```
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  stats     methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_0.11.1    functional_0.4 plyr_1.8.1     reshape2_1.2.2
[5] stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.0.2
```

Comment: Very strange behavior. Your second issue is as expected. If you split by `a` then `length(a)` should be 1.

Comment: @shadow, why wouldn't `dt[, list(length(b), length(a)), by=a]` return the same values for `a` and `b` since they are both variables in `dt`?  To put it slightly differently, if I added `a2` == `a` to the data table, would it not be odd that `length(a2)` and `length(a)` return different things?

Comment: Perhaps that would make more sense. But that's also what the `.N` variable is for and I guess since the value of `a` is constant, it is a matter of optimization to only use `a[1]`.

Comment: @shadow, that's a fair point.  Since `a` is one length it should always recycle appropriately anyway.

Comment: @Arun, thanks for tracking those down.  Added `sessionInfo()`

Comment: As of 2020, `data.table` works very unpredictably and messy with factors. I tend to avoid passing factors to any functions involving `DT` manipulation. Hard-to-trace bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three questions in your post. I'll answer them in order.

Referring to a factor column in `j` not retaining the class is fixed in 1.9.3 (bug #5437 IIRC). It was a tiny regression due to various enhancements in 1.9.0 (and some changes for R3.1.0 IIRC). Now tests are added to catch this as well.

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.3
dt <- data.table(a=factor(rep(c("a", "b"), 5)), b=1:10)
str(dt[, list(mean(b), a), by=a])

# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ a : Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": 1 2
#  $ V1: num  5 6
#  $ a : Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": 1 2
#  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

---

The issue with `.BY` is also fixed in 1.9.3:

```
dt[, print(.BY), by=a]
# $a
# [1] a
# Levels: a b

# $a
# [1] b
# Levels: a b

# Empty data.table (0 rows) of 1 col: a
```

---

```
dt[, list(mean(b), a[[2]]), by=a]
# Error in `[[.default`(a, 2) : subscript out of bounds
```

This is because variables/columns in `by` are by default available as `length=1` vectors. After all, it's the variable you're grouping by.

However, I've raised potential issues with this feature with @Matt and @eddi. You can find a brief discussion between me and @eddi [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23092028/559784) under comments. I've also written Matt about this and is currently under discussion. This will be soon resolved and documented, whatever the resolution is.

My stance as of now is that columns in `by` should not mask that of `dt`. This started from [bug #5191](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5191&group_id=240&atid=975), which is basically this:

```
DT <- data.table(x=1:5, y=6:10)
DT[, sum(x), by=x%%3L]
#    x V1
# 1: 1  1
# 2: 2  2
# 3: 0  0
```

Where the actual results should've been:

```
DT <- data.table(x=1:5, y=6:10)
DT[, sum(x), by=list(grp=x%%3L)]
#    grp V1
# 1:   1  5
# 2:   2  7
# 3:   0  3
```

The results weren't right because `by` column `x` masks the column `x` in `DT` corresponding to each group. In this case, this happened because we allow for expressions in `by`.

However, it extends even if it weren't the scenario. Consider the case:

```
> DT[, sum(y), by=list(y=x)]
#    y V1
# 1: 1  1
# 2: 2  2
# 3: 3  3
# 4: 4  4
# 5: 5  5
```

What happened here is that naming the by column `y` resulted in `y` from `DT` being masked.

IMHO, what should be done is that `by` shouldn't be masking the columns from `DT` that'll be used in `j` at all. Instead, if one needs to refer to the grouping variable, they should use the already existing `.BY` variable (or simply subset the first index with `[1L]`) as follows:

```
> DT[, print(.BY$x), by=x]
# [1] 1
# [1] 2
# [1] 3
# [1] 4
# [1] 5
# Empty data.table (0 rows) of 1 col: x
```

This is just my opinion and there might be other arguments for retaining the current feature and just fixing these potential buggy cases. We'll have to discuss it and get this resolved and depending on what we conclude, document it accordingly.

I'll update this post once that's been done :).

Comment: thanks for the super thorough answer.  I definitely agree with you about the masking.

Comment: Maybe a thread should be started on datatable-help to discuss the `by` issue, since it's potentially a large breaking change. As I've stated in our other discussion I think plain `by` column expressions should be atomic (as they are now), and the issues in the bug reports are all about complex `by` expressions.

Comment: @eddi, agreed that this should be on datatable-help. Will post soon. One question, just to clarify: Do you consider `DT[, y, by=list(y=x)]` as complex as well?

Comment: probably - so in that case I'd say `.SD` should contain `x` and then in that example there is the additional issue of what gets a priority in the `j`-expression - the `by`-element or the `.SD`-column (I think I'm currently leaning towards `.SD` column having priority - but I don't have as strong feelings about this as the other issue and can be easily persuaded to lean in the opposite direction)